# why does `docker create` take longer time after pulling an image

Tags: docker, containers

I have been stuck with this problem for a few days but don't find any answers.

I'm testing container provision performance on my machine. And I find that when you pull an image (`docker pull {image1}`) and create a container using the image **immediately**(`docker create {image1}`). The `docker create` command usually takes several seconds to complete. But if I wait for a few seconds after pulling, the `docker create` command finishes instantly,

At first, I think this might because the image needs to be unzipped after pulling before creating. But then I find it's not the reason. Assume that I have already pulled `image1`, then I pull `image2`. After pulling `image2`, I create a container **immediately** based on `image1`, the `docker create {image1}` command still needs several seconds to finish.

In summary, it looks like pulling any image affects the performance of creating a container using any image. This looks pretty weird to me.

To figure out the reason, I compiled the moby project and add some logs. It turns out that the `unmount` operation (this line https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/daemon/graphdriver/overlay2/overlay.go#L632) takes a lot of time if you create a container immediately after pulling an image.

I'd like to know why pulling an image affects the performance of creating a container. Even if the image you pull and the image used to create a container are different images.

Here is some info that may be useful for you to reproduce the issue.

Moby commit id: a9788886e6f9c94f93cab701eb33e189fd95b2ec
Host info: Ubuntu 20.04.1

The steps to reproduce the issue:

- `docker rmi docker tensorflow/tensorflow:latest` # make sure there's no `tensorflow/tensorflow:latest`  image on your machine
- `docker pull docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow:latest`
- `docker create ensorflow/tensorflow:latest` # run this command immediately after pulling this takes 3-5 seconds to finish